# Geocortex Workflow Designer Upload File

Tags: upload, base64, workflow

i was tring to create a workflow  with geocortex workflow designer that upload a file in folder. 
So to do that, i create a Form that make a file picker and it returns a IList of FileItem. 
than i would take the base64 data and write a file, but it show me an error:

> Geocortex.Forms.Client.FileItem.Friend Property FileDataBase64 As
>   String is not accessible in this context beacause it is 'Friend'

the scope of my variable its Flowchart and i can't understand why this error

this error is showned even if i try to access te variable inside the form activity even outside. 
thank's every one

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a security related issue.
Make sure that your target directory is writeable by Geocortex workflow.  Do a very basic test.

Again do every steps of the process in isolation, in order to pin-point the source of the problem.      Poliart.com

Comment: Hi, i found the problem, i was reading the wrong attribute, i try  to read FileItem.filedata and that attribute expose the bytes[] of the file.